# form not showing when i click on custom module menu

Tags: module, forms, 404

Form not showing when clicking on custom module menu.
Here's my code:

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
<menu>
    <add id="Test_Banners::first_level_demo"
         title="Shipping Vendor"
         module="Test_Banners"
         sortOrder="9999"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content" />



    <add id="Test_Banners::second_level_demo"
         title="Shipping Vendor Cost"
         module="Test_Banners"
         sortOrder="0"
         action="uiform/"
         parent="Test_Banners::first_level_demo"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content" />
</menu>
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="uiform" frontName="uiform">
            <module name="Test_Banners"/>
        </route>
    </router>
    /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/view/adminhtml/layout/ui_component/employee_form.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">employee_form.employee_form_data_source</item>
                <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">employee_form.employee_form_data_source</item>
            </item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">employee_form</item>
            </item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        </argument>
        <dataSource name="employee_form_data_source">
            <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Test\Banners\Model\DataProvider</argument>
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">employee_form_data_source</argument>
                <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
                <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            </argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Test/Banners/form/provider</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </dataSource>
        <fieldset name="employee_details">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <field name="employee_id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Id</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_id</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="employee_name">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Name</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="employee_salary">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Salary</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_salary</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
            <field name="employee_address">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Address</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_address</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
```

> /home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/Controller/Adminhtml/Employee/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Test\Banners\Controller\Adminhtml\Employee;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Action
{
protected $_pageFactory;

/**
 * Index constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
{
    $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}


/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
 */
public function execute()
{
    return $this->_pageFactory->create();
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @jhon, you don't need to ask a new question every time when you want to explain more. You can click on the edit link under question to add more update in it.

Comment: but no one can answer me on that post when post get older no one can post response on it

Comment: @jhonjhondoe layout file missing here.

Comment: here's my layout file
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/view/adminhtml/layout/uiform_index_index.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="employee_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

Comment: I cant get you basically I generate a new question both the question are same 
my problem is form is not showing on custom module menu link

Answer (score 2):

From here looking at your question you have worng path of ui component

wrong path

```
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/view/adminhtml/layout/ui_component/employee_form.xml
```

correct path

```
/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Test/Banners/view/adminhtml/ui_component/employee_form.xml
```

and change in menu.xml

```
<add id="Test_Banners::second_level_demo"
         title="Shipping Vendor Cost"
         module="Test_Banners"
         sortOrder="0"
         action="uiform/employee"
         parent="Test_Banners::first_level_demo"
         resource="Magento_Backend::content" />
```

because your controller path `uiform/employee/index`